# Can't convert values

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to convert the Id field to send it to the DB but in the DB the type is bigInt:

```
var ID_Inscricao = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1");
```

How do I convert this to a type that is compatible with bigInt? I have tried cast and convert but neither worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the value in the label's Text property to an integer of some sort:

```
string labelText = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;
var ID_Inscricao = Convert.ToInt64(labelText);
```

Beware that this could throw an exception if the text value is not a number.

Comment: Debug it and tell me what 'labelText' is?

Comment: After rebboting its give this "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated." the value of the os the label text its correct.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to take the `Text` property and convert that. You can't cast a control to a value.

*Hint:* Use the appropriate `TryParse`.

Comment: Its giving me this error "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: what is the datatype in your database?

Comment: The Type on the database its bigint

Comment: ok, now the problem passed to the ExecuteNonQuery(); it give the error : SqlException was Unhandled by user code/ String or binary data would be truncated. The Statement has been terminated."

Answer (score 1):

This may help you,

var ID_Inscricao = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1");

var ID_Inscricao_val = parseInt(ID_Inscricao.innerHTML);